# Proof that $B$ is a vector basis of $\oplus_{i=1} ^k W_i.$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$V$ is a vector-space , $W_i\subseteq V, 1\leq j \leq k $ independant sub-spaces, $B_i$ is a vector basis of $W_i$.

Define $B=\cup_{i=1}^k B_i$
Proof $B$ is a vector basis of $\oplus_{i=1} ^k W_i.$

My solution:

$v \in \oplus_{i=1} ^k W_i \implies v=\sum_{i=1}^k W_i \implies v=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{i=1}^j b_i $ ($j$ is the dimension of each $B_i$) $\implies v \in $ span $\{B\}.$

Now i show that $B$ is the minimal ordered set:

$W_i\cap W_j=\{ 0\} \implies B_i\cap B_j=\{ 0\}\implies $
dim$(B_i\cap B_j)=0 \implies $dim$(B_i\cup B_j)=$dim$(B_i)+$dim$(B_j) \implies $dim $B =$dim$(B_1)$+dim$(B_2) +\cdots +$ dim$(B_k)\implies $B$ $is the minimal ordered set $\implies B$ is a basis.

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: If the $B_i$ are bases, then $B_i\cap B_j$ cannot be $\{0\}$. That would imply that $0$ is an element of both $B_i$ and $B_j$, which is impossible (they would be linearly dependent). $\dim(B_i\cap B_j)$ is nonsense: dimension applies to spaces/subspaces, not to sets.  Also, you never bother saying that $i\neq j$, but that is minor. Finally: it is false that because you can do it two at a time then you can do it for all of then. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $B_1=\{(1,0)\}$, $B_2=\{(0,1)\}$, and $B_3=\{(1,1)\}$. There is a lot of work that needs to go between the 2-term and the $k$-term sums.

Comment: But if $B_i\cap B_j \neq \{0\}$ exists $\{0\} \neq v \in B_i\cap B_j  \implies \{0\} \neq v \in W_i\cap W_j$ no ? where i am wrong ?

Comment: The zero vector cannot be an element of a basis. I **think** what you meant to say is that the intersection of the bases is *empty*, but that's not what you said. Note also that "$\{0\}\neq v$" is a true statement for **any** vector, including $0$, because a vector is never equal to the set whose only element is the zero vector.

Comment: Can i say $B_i\cap B_j = \emptyset \implies$ dim $(B_i\cap B_j)=0 $ ? This is the only mistake in my proof ?

Comment: The fact that $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ lets you conclude that $B_i\cap B_j=\varnothing$, yes. But you still can't talk about the "dimension" of $B_i\cap B_j$ (again, dimension is something about *vector spaces* or *subspaces*, but $B_i\cap B_j$ is just a set of vectors!). You could say $\dim(\mathrm{span}(B_i\cap B_j))=0$, but that doesn't get you anywhere. It is *false* that if two linearly independent sets have empty intersection, then their union is  linearly independent, which is what you are trying to say in the next step. Compare $B_1=\{(1,0)\}$ and $B_2=\{(2,0)\}$.

Comment: This isn't anywhere near as easy as you are trying to make it. It won't be a simple chain of implications. There is a lot more work that needs to be done. For starters, note that the assumption on the $W_i$ is far stronger than just that any two of them intersect trivially: it is that any one of them intersects *the span of all the others* trivially. Without that assumption, the conclusion you want fails. So that assumption needs to be used, and used explicitly, somewhere along the line in your proof. What you are trying to do, proceedings pairwise, is doomed to fail.

Comment: Of your chain of six implications, none are correct, and I have no idea what "$B$ is the minimal ordered set" even means.